# How to fix error "The type entityClass_ is already defined?

Tags: rapidclipse

I use RapidClipse 4.0.1.2...

After working a while on a project I got a lot of errors like 
*"The type someEntity_ is already defined"*.

In this case I didn't define the entities myself.
All will be done by RapidClipse entity manager function.
I tried to clean up the project, I updated and rebuild it.
 
All without success.

I assume, that this is still a bug in RapidClipse, or it is a setting, which is wrong.

I checked with explorer one of the files and found following locations:
1) c:/MyWorkspace/workspace/rc07/target/classes/com/myuser/rc07/dal/
   In this path is KontoDAO_.class
2) c:/MyWorkspace/workspace/rc07/target/geranted-sources/annotations/com/myuser/rc07/dal/
   In this path is KontoDAO_.java
3) c:/MyWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins.org.eclipse.wst.server.core
   /tmp0/wtpwebapps/rc07/WEB-INF/classes/com/myuser/rc07/dal/
   In this path is KontoDAO_.class
4) c:/MyWorkspace/workspace/rc07/.apt_generated/com/myuser/rc07/dal/
   In this path is KontoDAO_.java
5) in the recycle of folder c:/MyWorkspace/workspace I had around 30 versions of KontoDAO_....

Does anyone know how to fix it, or how to set up the project to prevent this?

Thank you in advance
rgds OpaHeinz

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the target folder. Whenever you import entities after the project rebuild (in case you have automatic rebuild) these files get created in target/generated-sources/annotation folder.

Check there.

Comment: You can delete all those and re-build the project. I will always suggest while working on project, always use Versioning software.  So in case these issue occurs you can delete all entities_ and rebuild  the projects (in case any _ entities doesn't generate you will have backup.

Comment: In meantime the problem solved itself. No idea why, but the errors are gone ;-)
I didn't use versioning software due I am alone and working only for my fun and did dayly manualy version backups. But you are right I will give it a try.